# How to get free location / venue from two dates in sql

Tags: sql-server

If user inputs following data , i want to get free and Booked Locations

```
Start Date :   01/03/2015    
End Date   :   31/03/2015    
Start Time :   02:30 PM    
End Time   :   05:30 PM
```

I have Following table structure for storing locations date wise

```
Date         Day          StartTime  EndTime   Location
2015-03-01   Sunday       2:30 PM    05:30 PM  Location - A
2015-03-02   Monday       4:30 PM    05:30 PM  Location - B
2015-03-03   Tuesday      5:45 PM    06:45 PM  Location - C
```

output like :

```
Location - A       Booked
Location - B       Booked
Location - C       Free
```

Comment: Have you considered alternative table structures?

Comment: where do you save the booking status? how can you find which one is booked and which one isnt?

Answer (score 0):

Please check this sample.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (Date varchar(50), Day VARCHAR(50) ,StartTime varchar(50),  EndTime  varchar(50), Location VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @T VALUES('2015-03-01','Sunday','2:30 PM','05:30 PM','Location - A'),
('2015-03-02','Monday','4:30 PM','05:30 PM','Location - B'),
('2015-03-03','Tuesday','5:45 PM','06:45 PM','Location - C')

Declare @stdate datetime = '03/01/2015 2:30 PM' ,  --','
@endate datetime = '03/31/2015 5:29 PM'

--Result will be all booked
SELECT *,
    cast( date + ' ' + StartTime as datetime) actualdate, 
    case when cast( date + ' ' + StartTime as datetime) between @stdate and @endate then 'Booked'
    else 'free' end
FROM @T
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like that

```
declare @Start_Date date = '01/03/2015'
DECLARE @End_Date date = '31/03/2015'
DECLARE @Start_Time time ='02:30 PM'
DECLARE @End_Time time = '05:30 PM'

SELECT location
,      iif((Date = @Start_Date AND StartTime >= @Start_Time AND EndTime <= @End_Time),'booked','free')
FROM tbl
```